# How can I prevent 2 svg paths from being connected?

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

I am creating some kind of signature field, but I have the following unwanted behavior: when I draw for example 2 lines, at the beginning the second one looks like it is trying to connect to the first one and my question is how can I prevent that?

...in the example below I actually tried to draw 3 lines.

[image]

... **Edit:** I've edited and improved the example below based on the suggestions from @Danny'365CSI'Engelman and @chrwahl
and it now works for both desktop and mobile.

```js
let signature = document.getElementById('signature');
if (signature) {
    const appendNewSvgPath = function (e) {
        if (e.buttons === 1) {
            let intiialXY = ` ${e.offsetX} ${e.offsetY}`;
            svgpath = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "path");
            svgpath.setAttribute('d', `M${intiialXY} C${intiialXY.repeat(3)}`);
            signature.append(svgpath);
        }
    };
    const drawToSvgPath = function (e) {
        if (e.buttons === 1) {
            params.push(e.offsetX);
            params.push(e.offsetY);
            if (params.length === 6) {
                let d = svgpath.getAttribute('d');
                svgpath.setAttribute('d', `${d} ${params.join(' ')}`);
                params = [];
            }
        }
    };
    const clearPathParams = _ => params = [];
    
    let svgpath;
    let params = [];
    
    signature.onmousedown = appendNewSvgPath;
    signature.onpointerdown = appendNewSvgPath;

    signature.onmousemove = drawToSvgPath;
    signature.onpointermove = drawToSvgPath;

    signature.onmouseout = clearPathParams;
    signature.onpointerout = clearPathParams;

    signature.onmouseenter = appendNewSvgPath;
    signature.onpointerenter = appendNewSvgPath;

    signature.onmouseup = clearPathParams;
    signature.onpointerup = clearPathParams;
}
```

```css
body { 
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    margin: 0;
    height: 100vh;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: whitesmoke;
}

#signature {
    display: block;
    width: 800px;
    height: 300px;
    border: none;
    background-color: white;
    touch-action: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>
<body>
    <svg id="signature" stroke="blue" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" fill="none"></svg>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Maybe a check for mouseup, to clear your ``params`` array. BTW ``params.join(" ")`` is shorter than listing 6 values

Comment: @Danny'365CSI'Engelman - Thanks, that's exactly what the issue was ... for the .join(...  too

Answer (score 1):

In some cases the `params` array is not empty when when the `mousedown` event happens because the array is only emptied when it has the length of 6 (in the `mousemove` event listener). To avoid a partly filled array you should empty it on the mouse up event.

```js
let signature = document.getElementById('signature');
let svgpath;
let params = [];

if (signature) {
  signature.addEventListener('mousedown', e => {
    if (e.buttons === 1) {
      svgpath = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "path");
      svgpath.setAttribute('d', `M ${e.offsetX} ${e.offsetY}`);
      signature.append(svgpath);
    }
  });
  signature.addEventListener('mousemove', e => {
    if (e.buttons === 1) {
      params.push(e.offsetX);
      params.push(e.offsetY);
      if (params.length == 6) {
        let d = svgpath.getAttribute('d');
        svgpath.setAttribute('d', `${d} C ${params.join(' ')}`);
        params = [];
      }
    }
  });
  signature.addEventListener('mouseup', e => {
    params = [];
  });
}
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: whitesmoke;
}

#signature {
  display: block;
  width: 800px;
  height: 300px;
  border: none;
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<svg id="signature" stroke="blue" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" fill="none"></svg>
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, but on my side, cleaning up the params array onmousedown didn't work, I ended up doing that onmouseup.

Comment: Oh, yes, now I see the real problem. I updated my answer.